# How to check if an Event is cancelable from GWT code?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

Javascript events have [a "cancelable" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable).

How can this property be accessed from GWT code?  It is not exported in GWT [Event](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html) or [NativeEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html) classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JSNI:

```
  public native boolean eventIsCancelable(NativeEvent evt) /*-{
    return typeof evt.cancelable !== 'boolean' || evt.cancelable;
  }-*/;
```

Anyway, is calling

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

not enough?

Comment: Thanks, we finally did it using JSNI.  When we use preventDefault() on a non-cancelable event Chrome complaints with the message:  "Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted."  That's why we prefer to check first if the event is cancelable.

Comment: Instead of JSNI you should use JsInterop. You could use Elemental 2, and cast the `NativeEvent` to an Elemental event.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Could add an answer with an example? I always hear JsInterop but then I am unsure how to actually use.

Comment: `@JsType(isNative=true,namespace=JsPackage.GLOBAL,name="Event") class Event { public boolean cancelable; }` (or just use `elemental2.dom.Event` from elemental2-dom) then `Js.<Event>cast(event.getNativeEvent()).cancelable` (where `Js` is `jsinterop.base.Js` from jsinterop-base; or you could "double cast": `((Event) (Object) event.getNativeEvent()).cancelable`)